# Apache sqoop is not compiling

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I am trying to compile apache sqoop from source code as I need to build an extension of it. The code compilation is failing.

```
Code version from Git - 1.6. - https://github.com/apache/sqoop
ivy dependency can't be resolved for  org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26!jetty.zip

ant package command is giving following error

[ivy:resolve]       [FAILED     ] org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26!jetty.zip:  (0ms)
```

Comment: You should not be compiling Sqoop yourself unless you are attempting to help develop it. Try downloading a binary distribution from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/sqoop/1.4.5.

Comment: @abeaamase - Compiling your own open-source software really requires no justification. It's the whole point of being open source! Perhaps you're trying to add logging, or find and fix a bug. Perhaps some internal policy requires all production software to be built on-site after auditing the source. Perhaps you _want_ to help develop it, and compiling the original source is a perfectly reasonable first step - how else can you test a bugfix or feature you want to send upstream if you can't compile it?

Comment: OP:  I am looking for an answer to this issue myself. I suspect there is an upstream dependency causing this issue, and the solution may lie with the Ivy part of the build. I'll update when I know more.

Comment: @Hercynium good point. I chose the wrong words here. I was trying to convey that extending Sqoop1 isn't the best idea (Sqoop2 would be better for that). Any ways, my follow through below should help.

Comment: @abeaamase No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things I'd try:

1. Make sure you have the right versions of ant and maven. From the [COMPILING](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/COMPILING.txt) notes, Apache ant (1.7.1) at minimum is required.
2. Clear your [ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302119/ivy-cleancache-but-specific-folders) and [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache) cache.
3. Hit up the Sqoop [mailing lists](http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html) for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in my `~/.ivy2/com.cloudera.sqoop-sqoop-hadoop200.xml`:

```
<module organisation="org.mortbay.jetty" name="jetty">
  <revision name="6.1.26" status="release" pubdate="20150715114025" resolver="fs" artresolver="default" homepage="" downloaded="false" searched="false" default="false" conf="compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master" position="183">
    <metadata-artifact status="no" details="" size="2189" time="0" location="/home/sscaffidi/.ivy2/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/ivy-6.1.26.xml" searched="false" origin-is-local="true" origin-location="/home/sscaffidi/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.pom"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-common" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hbase" name="hbase-server" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="1.0.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-hdfs" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26" callerrev="2.2.0"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy" conf="compile, runtime" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.mortbay.jetty" name="jetty-sslengine" conf="compile, runtime" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="6.1.26.cloudera.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-hdfs" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <artifacts>
            <artifact name="jetty" type="zip" ext="zip" status="failed" details="" size="0" time="0"/>
    </artifacts>
  </revision>
  <revision name="6.1.26.cloudera.4" status="release" pubdate="20150720102423" resolver="fs" artresolver="default" evicted="latest-revision" evicted-reason="" homepage="" downloaded="false" searched="false" default="false" conf="compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master" position="-1">
    <metadata-artifact status="no" details="" size="7312" time="0" location="/home/sscaffidi/.ivy2/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/ivy-6.1.26.cloudera.4.xml" searched="false" origin-is-local="true" origin-location="/home/sscaffidi/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26.cloudera.4/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.4.pom"/>
    <evicted-by rev="6.1.26"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-common" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hbase" name="hbase-server" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="1.0.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy" conf="compile, runtime" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.mortbay.jetty" name="jetty-sslengine" conf="compile, runtime" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="6.1.26.cloudera.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-hdfs" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.4" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <artifacts>
    </artifacts>
  </revision>
  <revision name="6.1.26.cloudera.2" evicted="latest-revision" evicted-reason="" downloaded="false" searched="false" conf="compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master" position="-1">
    <evicted-by rev="6.1.26.cloudera.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-common" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy" conf="compile, runtime" rev="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26.cloudera.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26.cloudera.4" callerrev="2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"/>
    <artifacts>
    </artifacts>
  </revision>
</module>
```

The interesting line is this:

```
<caller organisation="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-hdfs" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" rev="6.1.26" rev-constraint-default="6.1.26" rev-constraint-dynamic="6.1.26" callerrev="2.2.0"/>
```

I'm not familiar with Ivy, but I'm guessing it means the `hadoop-hdfs` dependency wants jetty 6.1.26, when everything else wants `6.1.26.cloudera.4` or `6.1.26.cloudera.2`

I'm now trying to find the best way to make this work.

update: Found a solution

I don't know if this is a *good* solution - As I said, I don't know much about Apache Ivy - but it worked for me, and maybe it will work around this issue for you...

I added the following line to sqoop's `ivy.xml` file, just after the other `exclude` elements:

`<exclude org="org.mortbay.jetty" module="jetty" type="zip" />`

I hope somebody will correct me if I'm wrong, but this should prevent Ivy from trying to use the `zip` type artifact of jetty, and so it will fall-back to something else. In this case, it looks to me that it's using the `jar` type. Since the jar type is available at the repos ivy is already trying to use, it works.

At least, that's what it looks like to me :)

Comment: I also want to point out this patch in Pig's JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12707538/PIG-4484-1.patch